# API Вся история сделок на Binance

Tags: php, api, bitcoin

Есть ли какой-то способ получить историю сделок по api Binance?
Имеющийся способ может получить историю только конкретной пары, но как быть если нужна вся история?

Comment: пхп тут не причем. не в тот раздел вы обратились.

Comment: я понимаю, что php не причем, думаю api в целом для всех одинаково, а я просто пишу на php поэтому отметил этот тег

Comment: также интересует этот вопрос, если кто знает дайте ответ пожалуйста

Comment: Читайте документацию по API [https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#general-info]. Если есть официальные методы получения этой информации то там они должны быть описаны - если их там нет, то другими путями Вам этого не получить.

Comment: @phpBear в официальной документации нет метода для получения истории всех сделок, но, к примеру [тут](https://tradermake.money/) это как то реализовано..

Comment: Скорее всего у них своя история раз и официалов ее нет. Т.е они дают свое `API` - при его использовании историю они хранят у себя, а остальное через `API` официалов.

Comment: @phpBear У них это работает так: Вы подключаете к их сайту свои `api keys` с бинанса и их сайт в течении 3-5сек. отображает историю ваших сделок. То есть, они заранее мою историю сделок не видят)

Comment: Значит в `API` официалов есть метод позволяющий это реализовать - возможно он доступен не всем.